# phantom axis in eps images despite having set invisible axis in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, ghostscript, eps

I managed to put those line in my matplotlib code

```
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
```

in hopes of hiding the top, right, and left axes in the saved images. They worked fine in png images, but in the saved eps files, there are still boundaries (not sure whether they are axes) on the left and the top (the right axis indeed disappeared).

any ideas on how to hide the axis/frame boundaries when saving as eps images?

BTW: I don't want

```
ax.axis('off')
```

as I do need the bottom axis to work.

**EDIT**

I just did several tests with the following minimal working example, it turns out the axes will be invisible even in eps outputs if I either 
1) turn off rasterization in eps; 
or
2) turn off manual settings on xticks and xticklabels

However, both above features are what I absolutely need to keep in the eps output, so, any solutions?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
# setting up fig and ax
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
ax  = fig.add_axes([0.00,0.10,0.90,0.90])
# translucent vertical band as the only subject in the figure
# note the zorder argument used here
ax.axvspan(2014.8, 2017.8, color="DarkGoldenRod", alpha=0.3, zorder=-1)
# setting up axes
ax.set_xlim(2008, 2030)
ax.set_ylim(-2, 2)
# if you toggle this to False, the axes are hidden
if True :
    # manually setting ticks
    ticks = np.arange(2008, 2030, 2)
    ax.set_xticks(ticks)
    ax.set_xticklabels([r"$\mathrm{" + str(r) + r"}$" for r in ticks], fontsize=26, rotation=30)
    ax.get_xaxis().tick_bottom()
    ax.set_yticks([]) 
# hide all except for the bottom axes
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
# if you toggle this to False, the axes are hidden
if True :
    # this is to make sure the rasterization works.
    ax.set_rasterization_zorder(0)
# save into eps and png separately
fig.savefig("test.eps", papertype="a4", format="eps", bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.1, dpi=None)
fig.savefig("test.png", papertype="a4", format="png", bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.1, dpi=None)
```

and screenshot for eps

[image: eps]

and for png

[image: png]

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the said eps file ?

Comment: @Raiyan done, example code, new discovery, and figures shown.

Comment: Hey, I just ran your code in my computer; the eps does not have that black line on top.

Comment: @Raiyan now that's interesting, can you post your python and matplotlib versions? and linux? mine is matplotlib 1.3.1 and python 2.7.5

Comment: matplotlib 1.1.rc (just realized I forgot to update from the release candidate version), python 2.7.3, OS is ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @Raiyan alright, so it's the update from matplotlib screwed things up --- not sure if there is a solution now before it get fixed in the future.

Comment: just file a issue report on github/matplotlib. fingers crossed. https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2580

Comment: setting the axis color to something transparent works. tried and tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a work around, I would suggest adding this line of code:

```
ax.spines['top'].set_color((0,0,0,0))
```

I'm basically setting the top axis to transparent.

Comment: good tweak. I haven't tested but it should be working. I'll just wait a few more days to see if there's anything more of a destruction rather than camouflage.

Answer (score 2):

This was due to a bug in mpl (https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2473) which has been fixed (https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2479).

The problem is that the default color for the empty canvas in AGG was (0, 0, 0, 0) (fully transparent black) but eps does not handle alpha (it just gets dropped) so (0,0,0,0) -> (0,0,0) when shoved into an eps file. If you turn the axes off, that region of the canvas is never drawn too, hence it stays the default color. The accepted answer forces those pixels to get rendered (and composited onto a white background) during the rasterization so you don't see the black line in the eps file.